# Bash script to transverse a directory

Tags: bash, unix

I have a directory with XML files and other directories. All other directories have XML files and subdirectories, etc.

I need to write a script (bash probably) that for each directory runs `java XMLBeautifier directory` and since my skills at bash scripting are a bit rubbish, I would really appreciate a bit of help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have to get the directories, you can use:

```
$ find . -type d
```

just pipe this to your program like this:

```
$ find . -type d | xargs java XMLBeautifier
```

**Another approach** would be to get all the files with `find` and pipe that to your program like this:

```
$ find . -name "*.xml" | xargs java XMLBeautifier
```

This takes all `.xml` files from the current directory and recursively through all subdirectories. Then hands them one by one over with `xargs` to `java XMLBeautifier`.

Comment: Strangely enough not all the XML files have a .xml extension, but all files are XMLs

Comment: I was about to post just this. Beat me to it :(

Comment: @Michael, well, you can just change to whatever works for you. For instance, if all files under the directory structure, then just `find . -name "*"`

Comment: If the beautifier only takes one argument (e.g., a directory name), then use the second approach above, but add `-n 1` to the `xargs` call.

Answer (score 1):

Find is an awesome tool ... however, if you are not sure of the file name but have a vague idea of what those xml file contains then you can use grep.

For instance, if you know for sure that all your xml files contains a phrase "correct xml file" (you can change this phrase to what you feel appropriate) then run the following at your command line ...

```
grep -IRw "correct xml file" /path/to/directory/*
```

-I option searches the file and returns the file name when pattern is matched
-R option reaches your directory recursively
-w ensure that the pattern given matches on the whole and not single word individually

Hope this helps!